# Help needed throwing a ball in AS3

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, mouse, release

I'm working on a flash game, coding on the time line. 
What I'm trying to accomplish is the following:
With the mouse you swing and throw/release a ball which bounces against the walls and eventualy comes to point where it lays still (like a real ball).
I allmost had it working, but now the ball sticks to the mouse, in stead of being released, my question to you is: Can you help me make this work and explain to me what I did wrong?
You can simply preview my code by making a movieclip named 'circle' on a 550x400 stage.

```
            stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, circle_update); 

var previousPostionX:Number;
var previousPostionY:Number;
var throwSpeedX:Number;
var throwSpeedY:Number;
var isItDown:Boolean;
var xSpeed:Number   = 0;
var ySpeed:Number   = 0;
var friction:Number = 0.96;
var offsetX:Number  = 0;
var offsetY:Number  = 0;
var newY:Number = 0;
var oldY:Number = 0;
var newX:Number = 0;
var oldX:Number = 0;
var dragging:Boolean; 


  circle.buttonMode = true;
  circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, mouseDownHandler);
  circle.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, throwcircle);
  circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, clicked);
  circle.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, released);


  function mouseDownHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
      dragging = true;
      stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_UP, mouseUpHandler);
      offsetX = mouseX - circle.x;
      offsetY = mouseY - circle.y;
  }

  function mouseUpHandler(e:MouseEvent):void
  {
      dragging = false; 

  }



  function throwcircle(e:Event)
  {
      circle.x += xSpeed;
      circle.y += ySpeed;
      xSpeed *= friction;
      ySpeed *= friction;


  }

  function changeFriction(e:Event):void
  {
      friction = e.target.value;
      trace(e.target.value);
  }

    function circle_update(e:Event){

        if ( dragging == true ) { circle.x = mouseX - offsetX;
      circle.y = mouseY - offsetY; }

            if(circle.x + (circle.width * 0.50) >= 550){ circle.x = 550 - circle.width * 0.50; }
            if(circle.x - (circle.width * 0.50) <= 0){ circle.x = circle.width * 0.50; }
            if(circle.y + (circle.width * 0.50) >= 400){ circle.y = 400 - circle.height * 0.50;  }
            if(circle.y - (circle.width * 0.50) <= 0){ circle.y = circle.height * 0.50;   }
        }

    function clicked(theEvent:Event) {
    isItDown =true;
    addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, updateView);
    }

    function released(theEvent:Event) {
        isItDown =false;
    }

    function updateView(theEvent:Event) {
        if (isItDown==true){
            throwSpeedX =  mouseX - previousPostionX;
            throwSpeedY =  mouseY - previousPostionY;
            circle.x = mouseX;
            circle.y = mouseY;
        }
        else{
        circle.x += throwSpeedX;
        circle.y += throwSpeedY;
        throwSpeedX *=0.9;
        throwSpeedY *=0.9;
        }
        previousPostionX= circle.x;
        previousPostionY= circle.y;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Tidy up your code first:

- use only one ENTER_FRAME event (`circle_update`), and instead of adding/removing another listener, set a flag to true or false, e.g.:

  - replace `stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, drag);` with `dragging = true;`
  - replace `stage.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, drag);` with `dragging = false;`
  - add in `circle_update` method: `if ( dragging ) { /*code from drag method*/ }`
- use descriptive names, `throwCircle` should me `moveCircle`. Also, because so far there's going to be only one circle, move the code from `throwCircle` to `circle_update`
- remove duplicated code, e.g. one of these lines: `xSpeed *= friction;` and `throwSpeedX *=0.9;`
- you are adding another listener `updateView` in every `clicked` method, but you never remove it.

Comment: I made some changes, xspeed = the speed of the ball bouncing back from the walls and throwspeed are two diffrent things.